# How can I request a webpage that is a .txt file?

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve the page data from a webserver in which the URL is

http://www.xxxx.com/data.txt

Is there a way with client side javascript to do this? Does the webserver have to be configured to allow it?

John

Comment: It would work in the same way as requesting a normal HTML page.

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest if you want a JS solution or jQuery's `.ajax()`, `.get()` methods if you'd like a level of abstraction.

Comment: I have tried a xhr, but I don't think the site has any webservices and is on a different domain. I am making another xhr to a different domain that has JSON service and getting JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this in client side Javascript because of CORS.  If the server you are requesting the data from supports CORS you can do it client side.  However if the server you are requesting the data from does not support CORS you need to do the request server side and send it client side.

I would do this server side in a Node app and then fetch the data from your HTML page from the Node app.  Here is a little node script to do it.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    request = require("request");

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port);

app.get("/data", function (req, res) {
    request.get("http://www.xxxx.com/data.txt").pipe(res);
});
```

And then with JQuery on the client side you could do the following.

```
    $.get("/data", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure **javascript** :

```
var requestFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestFile.open('GET', 'http://www.xxxx.com/data.txt');
requestFile.onload = function() {
    // Here's your text file content ie. requestFile.responseText
    console.log(requestFile.responseText);
};
// Retrieve the text file
requestFile.send();
```

Or with **jQuery**

```
$.get('http://www.xxxx.com/data.txt', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: this wont really work unless the server he is requesting data from supports CORS

Comment: If the text file and the **javascript file** are in the `same domain` there's no need to **CORS** or **Nodejs**

Comment: The poster looks like they were trying to request a file from a different domain.

Comment: He did't say exactly if it's from same or different domain, but as I understand from the post he has access to the webserver so I supposed it's for same domain.

Comment: No, it's a different domain.

Comment: It's incorrect to call the first version `pure javascript` - it's the DOM API and not JavaScript here - that's what jQuery wraps. Anyway, in _modern_ DOM this is just `fetch("http://....").then(function(date) { ...})`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum how is it not pure JavaScript? I'm being serious, I have no idea what you're talking about and I'm interested to know.

Comment: @zfrisch I don't want to start a discussion in the comments, can you go to [the relevant room](chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) and ping me? (Like in comments that's @MyName)