# In Javascript, I have text data, need JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I asked a question ([How can I request a webpage that is a .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567703/how-can-i-request-a-webpage-that-is-a-txt-file)) about how to get a .txt file. Now that I have it, how do I turn it into JSON data?

Comment: Not really an answerable question in its current format (no code example, no data example, etc).  This all depends on what is in the text file.  At a high level, you need to read the data into a data structure and then serialize it to JSON.

Comment: So I'm guessing you're going to continue asking particular questions until the community has coded your entire application for you?

Comment: No, I'm trying to learn, and my little project requires something I haven't learned yet. If it bothers you, sorry. Thought others trying to learn might benefit. Thought that was what this forum was for, to learn...

Comment: @NCFatBoy Is the text you are receiving JSON formatted?

Comment: Basically what the comments are asking for is some knowledge that you attempted to do some research yourself and attempted some code. You asking a very vague question. It can be answered many ways but depends on more info from your end which you will need to provide or it will keep getting down voted, then flagged, then closed.

Comment: @NCFatBoy  This forum is meant for learning.  Part of that learning is learning how to formulate your questions so that people are not just guessing at what you want.

Comment: @NCFatBoy I get you're trying to learn, but this forum is not used to code things from scratch for you.  Usually when people post a question, it's accompanied with the code they've tried, they data they have and the expected output.

Comment: @entropic That's fine, I have some code I've written and I've learned how to fetch data via xhr from a different domain that supports CORS, and I've tried the same for this one to see if the site supports CORS which it doesn't. So the three questions I have asked were related to how to fetch data from a non-CORS supported domain. I obviously am not experienced writing javascript and am doing client side javascript so far. Now I know I have to learn Node.js and server side to accomplish some things. Apologize for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were going from your previous post, [How to fetch a .txt file from a different domain from server side javascript and get it client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569316/how-to-fetch-a-txt-file-from-a-different-domain-from-server-side-javascript-and), I am going to assume that you were from your question....

What you would need to do is parse the txt into JSON.  I would split the file with `txtFileContents.split("\r\n");`.  That will split the file line by line on the end of line.  Next I would loop over each line by line and try to determine what makes up a valid line.  In looking at your data I would check maybe that the first two characters are integers `parseInt(line.substring(0,2))` and then build an object.

```
var data [];

data.push({
    date: splitLine[0],
    time: splitLine[1],
    grossGen: splitLine[6],
    kerr: {
        inflow: splitLine[2],
        outflow: splitLine[3],
        hwGageElev: splitLine[4],
        dcpGageElev: splitLine[5],
        rainfall: splitLine[7]
    },
    islandCreek: {
        hwGageElev: splitLine[8],
        dcpGageElev: splitLine[9]
    }
});
```

I feel like in a giving mood today so here is a full code example.

https://github.com/jsloyer/node-fetch-txt-file.

Additionally you can deploy the solution to Bluemix with clicking the button below.
[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(yourString);
```

should turn a JSON-serialized string into JSON data. This should answer your question *assuming* the text you are getting is JSON-serialized.

Comment: Didn't downvote so can't undownvote - but hopefully downvoters will see  you've fixed it.

Comment: Yep, using JSON.parse is correct, answer well corrected, now guys remove your downvotes.

Comment: Edit still doesn't make sense. `JSON.parse()` will turn JSON-serialized string into an in-memory data structure. Not magically convert a text file into an a JSON string.

Comment: @MikeBrant I think the assumption here is that the data is already serialised as JSON

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I see nothing in the question that would lead me to believe the text file contains JSON.  If it did, why would the question even be asked as you would basically be asking "how do I convert JSON to JSON?",

Comment: @MikeBrant He's probably asking how to parse it with JS... we don't know enough to close it as a duplicate yet, however. Hence the title, "In Javascript, I have text data, need JSON data"

Comment: It looks like he mentions another post where he fetches a txt file

Comment: It is not JSON. It is text.